# Tekton run Git-Clone with non-root-user

Tags: kubernetes, git, cicd, pipeline

I am new to tekton I want to clone a public github repo. I created the service account and pv/pvc. However, when I try to run the pipelinerun I got permission denied error.

```
{"level":"error","ts":1702565666.2863512,"caller":"git/git.go:53","msg":"Error running git [init /workspace/output/]: exit status 1\n/workspace/output/.git: Permission denied\n","stacktrace":"github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git.run\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git/git.go:53\ngithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git.Fetch\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git/git.go:88\nmain.main\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init/main.go:53\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:250"}
```

It is is fixed when I edit the git-clone task and run as root user. However I don't want to run it with root user. How can I run it with non root user.

I also try to follow tekton doc about cloning: [link](https://tekton.dev/docs/how-to-guides/clone-repository/)

To install git-clone task for tekton [(ref to doc)](https://hub.tekton.dev/tekton/task/git-clone):

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tektoncd/catalog/main/task/git-clone/0.9/git-clone.yaml
```

or

```
tkn hub install task git-clone
```

Here is the pipeline I want o run: (you can use my git repo if you want it is public)

```
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ServiceAccount
    metadata:
      name: pipeline-account
    ---
    kind: Role
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: pipeline-role
    rules:
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["services"]
      verbs: ["get", "create", "update", "patch"]
    - apiGroups: ["apps"]
      resources: ["deployments"]
      verbs: ["get", "create", "update", "patch"]
    ---
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: RoleBinding
    metadata:
      name: pipeline-account-pipeline-role-binding
    roleRef:
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      kind: Role
      name: pipeline-role
    subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: pipeline-account
    ---
    apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
    kind: Pipeline
    metadata:
      name: blabla
    spec:
      params:
        - name: APP_REPO
          type: string
        - name: APP_REVISION
          type: string
      tasks:
        - name: git-clone
          params:
            - name: url
              value: $(params.APP_REPO)
            - name: revision
              value: $(params.APP_REVISION)
            - name: refspec
              value: ''
            - name: submodules
              value: 'true'
            - name: depth
              value: '1'
            - name: sslVerify
              value: 'true'
            - name: crtFileName
              value: ca-bundle.crt
            - name: subdirectory
              value: ''
            - name: sparseCheckoutDirectories
              value: ''
            - name: deleteExisting
              value: 'true'
            - name: httpProxy
              value: ''
            - name: httpsProxy
              value: ''
            - name: noProxy
              value: ''
            - name: verbose
              value: 'true'
            - name: gitInitImage
              value: >-
                gcr.io/tekton-releases/github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init:v0.44.5
            - name: userHome
              value: /home/git
          taskRef:
            kind: Task
            name: git-clone
          workspaces:
            - name: output
              workspace: shared-workspace
      workspaces:
        - name: shared-workspace
    ---
    apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
    kind: PipelineRun
    metadata:
      name: clone-test-blabla
    spec:
      podTemplate:
        securityContext:
          fsGroup: 65532
      params:
        - name: APP_REPO
          value: 'https://github.com/kaanatesel/tektontest.git'
        - name: APP_REVISION
          value: main
      pipelineRef:
        name: blabla
      serviceAccountName: pipeline-account
      timeouts:
        pipeline: 1h0m0s
      workspaces:
        - name: shared-workspace
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: shared-ws-test
```

Here is my pv/pvc

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: shared-ws
    spec:
      capacity:
        storage: 2Gi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
      hostPath:
        path: /mnt/gitclone
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: shared-ws-test
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
```